# Ubuntu ultrabook

Tags: power-management, battery, macbook, ultrabook

I have a question considering ubuntu & ultrabooks. The problem is, a need a new computer. I'm looking for an ultrabook-like laptop which runs with long battery life (even under ubuntu) but I don't want to switch back to windows. I checked some web pages and most ultrabooks just don't have a good battery performance with ubuntu. 
A possible alternative would be a Macbook (because most of the features I use with ubuntu are implented in one or another way in Macbooks as well) but I really do **not want** to buy one.

So I was wondering if you have experience or tips what kind of computer would be suitable. Alternatively, if there is another linux distr. which has better battery performance, any tip would also be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic here. Try [hardwarerecs.se], [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) or [Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com).

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-9350-laptop-ubuntu/pd

This is an ultrabook that Dell specifically tweaked to work with Ubuntu. Do with that what you will.